# How do I get a Lemon parser to terminate itself on a newline?

Tags: parsing, token, eol, lemon

Following [this old tutorial](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_lemon_tutorial.html), I am trying to get a lemon parser to automatically terminate parsing on an `EOL` token. The relevant part of [the parser](https://github.com/theory/flex-lemon-example/blob/166d26471a194a3fb12e0f09c5aec340e2157d6f/shellparser.y) looks like this:

```
start ::= in .
in ::= .
in ::= in commandList EOL .
{
    printf("start ::= commandList .\n");
    printf("> ");
}
```

Here's how I'm [executing the parser](https://github.com/theory/flex-lemon-example/blob/166d26471a194a3fb12e0f09c5aec340e2157d6f/main.c) with tokens scanned by Flex:

```
int lexCode;
do {
    lexCode = yylex(scanner);
    Parse(shellParser, lexCode, yyget_text(scanner));
    // XXX This line should not be necessary; EOL should automatically
    // terminate parsing. :-(
    if (lexCode == EOL) Parse(shellParser, 0, NULL);
} while (lexCode > 0);
```

I'd like to eliminate the need to check for the `EOL` token here, and just let the parser figure out when it's done. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the lexer is matching the correct pattern `"\n"` and submitting the correct token `EOL`?

Answer (score 1):

In EBNF terms your definition of `in` is

```
in ::= (commandList EOL)*
```

Which allows multiple EOLs. What you want is

```
in ::= commandList* EOL
```

Which should work out to

```
start ::= in EOL .
in ::= .
in ::= in commandList .
```

Note that this does not allow for completely empty input (not even an EOL); you can tweak things as necessary if this is a problem.

Comment: So I tried that, and it seems to work as well as what I had before, but it does not implicitly equate to passing `0` to the `Parse()` function. So it never reduces to any of those productions. I still have to do it myself. Which is fine if that's the way it works, but if not, I'd like to figure out the proper incantation.